# How does Cassandra stress test determine threadcount?

Tags: cassandra

I ran a Cassandra stress-test and the output came back to between 4 and 913 threadcounts. What causes Cassandra to increase and stop the threadcount?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Cassandra Stress, I see these tests
First, Cassandra starts with a small amount of thread and displays the result, then it also raises the thread until (This number seems to depend on the cluster that Cassandra has attached to stress and allowed to connect. Given this parameter, thread are counted.)ends the test.
And in the end, the results of all the tests with the number of thread they used in testing them in

[image]

As you can see above, the system I tested on was able to run 32 threads and the test was completed with the same amount and the results were displayed.